# Problems while trying to handle ValueError: No tables found with pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, append

I would like to read and create a dataframe from all the tables that live in a sequence of links. Let's say I have:

```
list_links = ['url1.com', 'url2.com', 'url3.com',...,'urln.com']
```

Then:

```
for url in lis:
    try:
        df = pd.read_html(url,index_col=None, header=0)
        lis.append(df)
        frame = pd.concat(url, ignore_index=True)
    except:
        pass
```

Nevertheless, I can not get the dataframe, nothing happens:

```
In: frame

Out:

In: print(frame)

Out:
```

Which is the correct way of getting the appending in a single table all the tables that live in each link?. Note that some links don't have a table... for that reason I tried `pass`. Also I tried this:

```
import multiprocessing
def process_url(url):
    df_url = pd.read_html(url)
    df = pd.concat(df_url, ignore_index=True) 
    return df_url

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
pool.map(process_url, lis)
```

Then:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-46e04cfd0bfe> in <module>()
      7 
      8 pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
----> 9 pool.map(process_url, lis)

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in map(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    258         in a list that is returned.
    259         '''
--> 260         return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
    261 
    262     def starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None):

/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    606             return self._value
    607         else:
--> 608             raise self._value
    609 
    610     def _set(self, i, obj):

ValueError: No tables found
```

I also tried this:

```
import multiprocessing
def process_url(url):
    df_url = pd.read_html(url)
    df = pd.concat(df_url, ignore_index=True) 
    return df_url

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=4)
try:
    dfs_ = pool.map(process_url, lis)
except: 
    pass
```

And nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Your not actually joining the dataframes. What if you try this:

```
df_list = []
for url in list_links:
    try:
        df = pd.read_html(url, index_col=None, header=0)
        df_list.append(df)
    except:
        pass

df = pd.concat(df_list)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help alex, I got this: `TypeError: cannot concatenate a non-NDFrame object` in `----> 9 df = pd.concat(df_list)`

Comment: Do you want to stack them: extend the columns by adding more rows or extend the rows by adding more columns. Depending on what you want to do you can try setting the axis parameter to 0 or 1. Also try my new suggestion above

Comment: Thanks again!... I tried with both (in concat) and I got the same exeception.

Comment: With the second I got: `ValueError: No tables found`

Comment: I see, so the try except method is better because it avoids this error. Your going to have to look more into that error. You could try concatenating only some dataframes and see if you can identify the problematic ones. Alternatively you can try using the join and merge dataframe methods. Best of luck.